# Can't figure out gulp autoprefixer and watch form

Tags: css, gulp

When I use gulp styles it just pipes the initial code to the destination without autoprefixing and when I'm trying to use gulp watch on styles function it starts but never ends.

I'm using Gulp 4

gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        gulp.src('style.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
       resolve();
    });
});



gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('style.css', gulp.series('styles'));
});
```

Terminal output

PS C:\Users\OneDrive\testGulp> gulp watch

[19:00:23] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\testGulp\gulpfile.js

[19:00:23] Starting 'watch'...

File tree structure
[image: My file tree]

Comment: You are watching styles.css, but your src is style.css

Comment: Checked it, still doesn't work

Comment: same error? Not watching? Or not prefixing?

Comment: Yes, still not finishing and not prefixing

Comment: @Demon probably you need to check the path where you have your css file. Are you sure the paths are correct? Can you provide your file tree structure?

Comment: @Akis Added file tree structure. It's not a complex project so I don't think the problem is in paths

Comment: Can you create a sandbox that reflects your project file structure?

Comment: You mean a diagram?